# Returning a String[] in java

Tags: java, string, compilation, return

How do you return an array String in Java? I keep getting error messages saying I can't convert from a String to a String[], but it shouldn't be attempting to do that. I'm pretty new to CS, so I'm not entirely sure. Here's my class file:

```
public class questionOrder {
    public String[] order(int x, String W, String X, String Y, String Z){
           String f = W;
           String g = X;
           String h = Y;
           String j = Z;

    switch(x){

        case 1: String[] ar = {f,g,h,j};
        return ar;

    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, you don't appear to be returning anything if you don't take case 1.

Comment: Always use default when using switch statement.

Comment: *"I'm pretty to new to CS ..."* - well one thing you need to learn is the importance of following coding standards.  1) Java class names start with an uppercase letter.  2)  Java variable and parameter names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: " Here's my class file:"  I think this is your source file, class file has different meaning in java.

Comment: @user1971739 Which IDE are you using? Eclipse for example gives a much better error message which helps you identify the problem more easily.

Answer (score 5):

If `x != 1` then the switch statement won't match and `return ar` will not be executed, so nothing will be returned from your function. I'm not sure why you are getting an error about converting a `String` to a `String[]` but I suspect it is a result of something you did not post in your code snippet.

Add the following to make it compile:

```
switch (x) {
    case 1:
        String[] ar = {f, g, h, j};
        return ar;
    default:
        return new String[0];
}
```

Comment: I know I wouldn't be returning anything if x wasn't 1, I stopped adding cases right after I saw the compile error. I'm using Eclipse, and the exact error says "This method must return a result of type String[]"

Comment: @user1971739 The above compiles, so your code snippet does not have the line with the error, please edit the OP with the line that has the error you describe.

Comment: @user1971739 The message you quote is not about conversion, but about not returning the required String[] result on some paths through the code.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Ah, I assumed he also meant he had a default case, good catch. (The error he quoted made me scratch my head for the same reason you pointed out, hence why I asked him to edit in more)

Comment: @user1971739 - The message says it all.  You must return `String[]`, and you're not doing that except for the one case.

Answer (score 0):

See this Example I was tried and Executed:

```
public class QuestionOrder {
public String[] order(int x, String W, String X, String Y, String Z){
       String f = W;
       int g = x;
      // g.toString();
      String h1 = Integer.toString(g);

       String h = Y;
       String j = Z;
  String[] ar=new String[] {f,h1,h,j};;

return ar;
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    try{
QuestionOrder q=new QuestionOrder();
String[] str=q.order(2,"e","r","t","y");
for (int i=0;i<str.length ;i++ )
{
    System.out.println(str[i]);
}

}catch(Exception e){}   }
```

}